How to change my appbundle in Google Play Console?
I developed an Android app, I uploaded the app bundle in Google Play Console. But my app got rejected for bad permissions uses. I updated my code and I created a new app bundle file (.aab). The problem here is that I didn't found where to change my app bundle file in my release.
So I created a new release, but I has to change the app version, they didn't allow to me to have two releases with the same app version. I just want to know if there is an solution to change the app bundle file in an existing release ?
Thank you for your time (and sorry for my bad English)

So far in similar cases, I have incremented the APK version number , created a new release and uploaded the new aab

If the version has not been released to any user, usually you can delete it to be able to release with the same version code
discard any track with this bundle, then go to app bundle explorer and chose the app bundle version you want to delete, if you are able to delete the bundle you will see that in the upper right corner remove bundle or remove apk
